# Substring from index 1 until the end of string

Tags: c, string, substring

Let's say I have

```
char* string = "1234567";
```

What's the easiest way to get the string `"234567"`?

Comment: `new_string = string + 1;`

Comment: Seems to be a XY problem. What actually you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set a pointer to point at the second character, with something like one of the following:

```
char *fromSecondChar = string + 1;
char *fromSecondChar = &(string[1]);
```

Note that this isn't going to do what you want for an empty string, you should probably check that first:

```
char *fromSecondChar = string;
if (*string != '\0') fromSecondChar++;
```

Also keep in mind that this is a pointer into the string literal itself, so the normal rules of modification apply (don't try to do it). If you want a *separate* staring that you can modify, you'll need to `strcpy` it to somewhere else.

Or you could `strdup` from the second character if you're happy with a dynamically allocated buffer and your implementation actually *has* a `strdup` (it's not mandated by the ISO C standard). That could be done with something like:

```
char *fromSecondChar = strdup (string + 1);
if (fromSecondChar == NULL)
    doSomethingIntelligent();
:
free (fromSecondChar); // at some point.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the substring should be in a separate memory, then you can do like as below.

```
char new_string[max_size];
strcpy(new_string, old_string + 1);
```